# PMR446 interferes with small electronics?

Tags: interference

Some small electronic devices react to PMR446 adversely temporarily, when exposed to a PMR446 transmitter, during the transmission.

- Portable DVD player: Green horizontal stripes on screen. Increasing if I hold the PMR446 transmitter near.
- Portable CD player (discman): Laser lens loses track, CD spins up very fast; also indicating low battery.
- Boombox CD player: Skips and noise hearable if too near to laser lens + fart sound at speakers.
- Standalone DVD recorder: Nothing, surprisingly.
- DECT unit: Display brightness decreases temporarily.
- USB Multimeter: Display lower current than actually flowing (e.g. 1.2A instead of 1.6a). Sometimes, voltage jumps up to 9.99V (highest displayable amount).
- CD boombox: Fart sound from speaker.
- Toy robot: Do random moves.
- Toy phone *benign girl*: Decreased speaker volume; ability to be enabled by the PMR446 signal.
- Portable standalone LED torch gets dimmed.

How can these interferences be explained technically?

Comment: Is this a proper PMR radio or a generic UHF handheld radio tuned to the PMR channels?

Comment: @MrGerber It is a Stabo portable PMR transmitter, Freecomm 650. Does that matter?

Comment: Yes, because proper approved PMR446 radios has maximum power output of 500mW, but your run of the mill Chinese UHF radio is typically 5W transmit power

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *electromagnetic interference*.

Effectively every wire in every piece of electronics is a radio reciever to some extent. When placed next to a strong transmitter they will recieve a signal, which may be interpreted as a control signal.

Systems are supposed to be designed to minimise the effect of this, but that costs money and is often skimped on.